# How to access a Class Defined In A Module From Outside A Module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-module

I cannot access one class from another. Classes are defined in different files.

```bsh
#foo.ps1
Class Foo { static [string]$data }
```

```bsh
#bar.ps1
using module ".\foo.ps1"
class Bar {
    Bar() {
        [Foo]::data="test" #not working
    }
}
[Foo]::data="test" #works
```

Comment: `foo.ps1` -> `foo.psm1`

Comment: PetSerAl: thank you it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer so this doesn't go unanswered (credit to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)).

Rename `foo.ps1` to `foo.psm1` so that PowerShell knows it's a module.